# Не могу написать простецкий телеграмм бота погоды. Ошибка NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python, telebot

Начал изучение три дня назад, по видео урокам на ютубчике, очень понравилось и по старым гайдикам писал телеграмм бота с прогнозом погоды от OpewWeather. Эхо бот работает и прогноз погоды тоже, но к сожалению **по отдельности**.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('MY_TOKEN', config_dict)
bot = telebot.TeleBot("MY_TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    mgr = owm.weather_manager() 
    status = weather.detailed_status
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    observation.weather.detailed_status
    weather = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text).weather
    temp = weather.temperature('celsius')['temp']

answer ="В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + status + "\n"
answer += "Температура воздуха равна + {temp}" + "\n\n"
if temp < 5:
    answer += "На улице холодно, рекомендуется одеть курту, шапку и теплый свитер."
elif temp < 10:
    answer += "На улице прохладно, рекомендуется одеть сезонную куртку и свитер."
elif temp > 15:
    answer += "На улице благоприятная погода, но не рекомендуется выходить без кофты."
elif temp > 20:
    answer += "На улице жарко, не забудьте одеть головной убор."
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Ковырял почти сутки pyTelegramBotAPI все данные и таблицы, но к сожалению так и не смог прийти к ответу.

```
answer ="В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + status + "\n"
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

ошибка выглядит так, но они по сути весь день менялись...

Прошу укажите на ошибку или может где искать ответ, заранее **больше спасибо**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас видимо ошибка в табуляции. В Python блок кода выделяется при помощи табуляции, если это функция, то вся её логика, должна быть на одном уровне табуляции.
Вы пытаетесь обратится к переменной message, а она является локальной для функции send_welcome, вне этой функции message не существует.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('MY_TOKEN', config_dict)
bot = telebot.TeleBot("MY_TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    mgr = owm.weather_manager() 
    status = weather.detailed_status
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    observation.weather.detailed_status
    weather = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text).weather
    temp = weather.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer = f"В городе {message.text} сейчас {status}\n"
    answer += f"Температура воздуха равна {temp}\n\n"
    if temp < 5:
        answer += "На улице холодно, рекомендуется одеть курту, шапку и теплый свитер."
    elif temp < 10:
        answer += "На улице прохладно, рекомендуется одеть сезонную куртку и свитер."
    elif temp > 15:
        answer += "На улице благоприятная погода, но не рекомендуется выходить без кофты."
    elif temp > 20:
        answer += "На улице жарко, не забудьте одеть головной убор."

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: То есть нужно добавить функцию message ?

Comment: @TonyBread, нет. Я вам уже все сделал, используйте мой код. А чтобы понять в чём проблема, найдите разницу между моим и вашим кодом.  И почитайте об области видимости в Python, это вам поможет.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @TonyBread , если я вам помог отметьте мой ответ, как решение, чтобы другие понимали.

Comment: Бот кстати заработал, запускается  но теперь при отправке сообщения answer не принимает **NameError: name 'answer' is not defined**, наверное мне стоит еще разок перечитать документацию, мне очень не ловко, прощу прощения

Comment: @TonyBread, всё та же причина ошибки, функция echo_all, не видит answer в области видимости. Я поправил код, теперь будет всё работать. Вот причитаете эту статью https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/487952/ и вы всё поймете.